# How can I Reduce unused JavaScript in Nuxt website?

Tags: performance, vue.js, nuxt.js, pagespeed

I have created my first Nuxt website .I want to work on the performance of this app , specially speed . Anyone can recommend some resources or videos for that. Mainly, reduce unused JavaScript  and stuff.

Comment: SO is not a place for how-to tutorials/resources but you could look here: https://web.dev/learn/ They have a whole `performance` section and since Web Core Vitals are done by the Google team, checking their resources is always nice!